# Error running Cassandra + Pig

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig, cassandra-2.0

I am using the cassandra/example/pig/bin/pig_cassandra script to run Pig scripts on Cassandra.
I am getting error while executing **rows = LOAD 'cassandra://schema1/users' USING org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CassandraStorage();**

Error: 
    ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1069: Problem resolving class version numbers for class org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CassandraStorage

I am running cassandra 2.0.3, pig 0.12.0 with java 7 on mac os x 10.9

```
.bash_profile contains 
export PIG_HOME=~/pig-0.12.0-src
export PIG_CONF_DIR=~/hadoop-1.0.4/conf
export PIG_INITIAL_ADDRESS=localhost
export PIG_RPC_PORT=9160
export PIG_PARTITIONER=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
```

Kindly guide me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you please paste overall steps you had followed for pig+cassandra , i had already seen a lot of tutorials but getting same exceptions as you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try using CqlStorage as below?

rows = LOAD 'cql://schema1/users' USING CqlStorage();